# can't understand Error encountered: Message: Element was not present

Tags: selenium-webdriver, seleniumbase

Sorry, I am still learning the Python language and I am trying to apply it to this site, but I cannot understand the problem. Can you help?

```
    from seleniumbase import SB
    
    # OPEN LOGIN PAGE
    with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(
        "https://visa.vfsglobal.com/egy/en/hrv/login",
        reconnect_time=12
    )
    print("Site: VFS Global OPEN LOGIN PAGE >>>>> Success")
    
    # Define functions
    def login():
        # Search For Cookies
        sb.click("#onetrust-reject-all-handler")
        sleep(3)
    
    while True:
    try:
        login()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error encountered: {e}')
    finally:
        sleep(2)
        quit()  # Indentation adjustment needed here

# End of your script
```

Terminal

```
 Site: VFS Global OPEN LOGIN PAGE >>>>> Success Error encountered: Message:   
    Element {#onetrust-reject-all-handler} was not present after 7 seconds!
```

But when delete

```
def login():
```

everything work fine why this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the cookie section at the bottom of the page. If you're just trying to click the Turnstile, this will do:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(
        "https://visa.vfsglobal.com/egy/en/hrv/login",
        reconnect_time=8
    )
    sb.driver.uc_switch_to_frame("iframe")
    sb.driver.uc_click("span.mark")
    breakpoint()
```

(If your internet connection is slow, raise the `reconnect_time`.)